# bulk change filenames inside a folder containing {}

Tags: powershell

i am trying to bulk change the name of the files in a folder but when i am trying to replace "{2}" with "_" using powershell command ls *.* | Rename-Item -NewName {$.name -replace "{2}",""} I got an error message

Rename-Item : The input to the script block for parameter 'NewName' failed. The regular expression pattern {2} is not valid. At line:1 char:31

My file name is RO_omvp436_813_AF_ANCPI_50075_10{2}28{2}2010 it should be RO_omvp436_813_AF_ANCPI_50075_10_28_2010

Comment: `... -replace '\{2\}', '_'` or `... -replace [regex]::Escape('{2}'), '_'`